# Как вставить массив php в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ключи и значения собираю в строку с помощью `implode`.
Как вставить их в `mysql`?

`$table` - название таблицы
`$data` - массив

```
$worker = ['id' => '', 'first_name' => 'aleks', 'last_name' => 'snake', 'title' => 'programmist', 'age' => 31, 'salary' => '65000'];
public function insert($table, $data) {
    $key = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
    $value = implode(', ', array_values($data));
    $post = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, "INSERT INTO $table ($key) VALUES      ($value)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задача стоит в сохранении в MySQL, я не рекомендую использовать Ваш способ. Могу предложить следующий:

```
public function insert($table, $data) {
    $data = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
    $post = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, "INSERT INTO $table (`column`) VALUES ($data )");
}
```

А если все-же хотите такой, как у Вас:

```
public function insert($table, $data) {
    $key = '`'.implode('`, `', array_keys($data)).'`';
    $value = '"'.implode('", "', array_values($data)).'"';
    $post = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, "INSERT INTO $table ($key) VALUES      ($value)");
}
```

Но это скорее из категории "плохая практика". Вышеуказанный код годится, если поля в таблице в БД используют строчный тип... В противном случае будут проблемы.
Конечно можно сделать проверки типа... Но тогда Вам проще использовать первый вариант или готовое решение

Comment: спс, то есть я так понял проблема была в кавычках. Насчёт первого  примера зачем кодировать массив в json? И как тут $post = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, "INSERT INTO $table (`column`) VALUES ($data )"); я перечисляю все столбцы таблицы и соответствующие значения массива?

Comment: @aleks, зависимо от задачи. Если нужно сохранить массив, но при этом не нужно манипулировать им средствами SQL, то вариант не плохой

Answer (score 0):

Советую посмотреть в сторону типа поля JSON и хранить массив в этом формате. Правда будут некоторые ограничения с "манипуляцией им средствами SQL" и некоторый ущерб скорости операции (не критично на небольших базах). Некоторые поля из json могут автоматически записываться в назначенные ячейки с помощью GENERATED.

*это скорее дополнение ответа @Node_pro, но репутация не позволяет мне пока оставлять комментарии*